# create new row after every 3 column in loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So what i want to do is want to create a new row after every 3 column printing in php with bootstrap column with foreach loop here is my code

```
<div class = "row">
<?php   foreach($location_list as $location) 
     {

  echo "<div class ='col-md-4'>
          <hr> $location->address </hr>
           <hr> $location->name </hr>
           <hr> $location->pin </hr>
       </div> ";
}

  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your div with class row inside foreach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code to print `row` should be inside `foreach` loop in  a specific condition. And the condition for printing row should be as:

```
<?php
foreach ($location_list as $key => $location) {
    if ($key % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div class = "row">';
    }

    echo "<div class ='col-md-4'>
          <hr> $location->address </hr>
           <hr> $location->name </hr>
           <hr> $location->pin </hr>
       </div> ";

    if ($key % 3 == 2) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```