# Add new columns container every 3 column elements in React.js with Bulma.css

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I create a new react component called  that displays some user info.
I have every user data in an array of objects.
I want to create a layout that shows every 3 users in a row container (columns for Bulma css framework) with a column element for each user.

I check others questions like this [create new row after every 3 column in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471631/create-new-row-after-every-3-column-in-loop)  and all use non-closing tags in HTML for creating the layout but in React.js all the tags must have a closing tag.

```
users: [
{id:1, name: Tomas}
{id:2, name: Tomas}
{id:3, name: Tomas}
{id:4, name: Tomas}
{id:5, name: Tomas}
{id:6, name: Tomas}
]


return (
 ////

 const users = users.map(user,index) => {
  if (index % 3 === 0) {
  /// some code to create the layout
   }

  return <div className="column><User name={client.name}/></div>

  }
///
)
```

I want to render something like this

```
<div className="columns">
  <div className="column">
    <User id={users.id} name={users.name}/> // id 1
  <div>
  <div className="column">
    <User id={users.id} name={users.name}/> // id 2
  <div>
  <div className="column">
    <User id={users.id} name={users.name}/> // id 3
  <div>

</div>

<div className="columns">
  <div className="column">
    <User id={users.id} name={users.name}/> // id 4
  <div>
  <div className="column">
    <User id={users.id} name={users.name}/> // id 5
  <div>
  <div className="column">
    <User id={users.id} name={users.name}/> // id 6
  <div>

</div>
```

How can I make this layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In React you can't generate code like you would do with server rendering like PHP or Ruby.

First, you have to split your array into sub arrays, and you can define a method for it:

```
const splitEvery = (array, length) =>
  array.reduce(
    (result, item, index) => {
      if ( index % length === 0 ) result.push([])
      result[Math.floor(index / length)].push(item)
      return result
    },
    []
  )
```

Then, in your render method, you can cycle the splitted array:

```
return (
  <div>
  {
    splitEvery(users, 3).map(usersChunk => (
      <div className="columns">
        { usersChunk.map( user => (
            <div className="column">
              <User key={user.id} id={user.id} name={user.name} />
            <div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code works perfectly but I made an error writing the code that I want to render. Sorry about that.

Comment: You're the best! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while, but just want to note this down here for anyone else coming across this.

Depending on your use case for this, you might not want to generate set columns like this each time as they won't scale nicely on displays - if it's too wide for the screen you might end up with overflow.

To ensure that the # of items in each row scale nicely, consider using a single `is-flex-wrap-wrap`

```
<div className="columns is-flex-wrap-wrap">
  {
    users.map((user, i) => {
      <div className="column" key={"row" + i}>
        <User id={user.id} name={user.name} />
      </div>
    });
  }
</div>
```

Additionally, if you need to ensure that every user has the same height, you can add `is-flex` to the column-div.